# Preload random image from Unsplash using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to preload an image called from Unsplash URL:

```
https://source.unsplash.com/random.
```

As you can see this URL  returns an URL of random image. I'm trying to preload returned image, but I can't get returned URL of selected images.

```
var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';
    image.onload = function(){
      element.css('background', 'url('+ image.src + ') no-repeat center center fixed');
    };
```

While this works on Chrome, where changed a background image doesn't make a blank screen while loading, on Safari it won't work.

I suspect in Safari URL will be called again for another image on success event and will make blank screen for new image loading.

I'm using AngularJS, is there any way when I call random URL, I get a returned URL of the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://source.unsplash.com/random";
$("#somewhere-to-append-the-image").hide(0).append(image);
image.onload = function() {

    var img = $("#somewhere-to-append-the-image > img");

    // work with the img here
    $("#somewhere-to-append-the-image").fadeIn(100);
}
```

Sadly, you will still not get the real url of the image in img.attr("src") or any way to reference that same image again in the future.

The reason for this is because it is a 302 redirect, and the client-side script cannot intercept the 302 redirect, it is resolved automatically and you cannot do anything about that. You can read 302 headers on the server side though, so that's the only workaround to getting the real URL.  So you'd have to make an ajax request to your server, have it resolve the 302, and respond with the correct URL.  Then the above code I wrote can still be used with the resolved url for preload purposes.

I'm pretty sure Unsplash have set it up like this on purpose because of what I read on their website:

> Hotlinking Unlike most APIs, we **prefer for the image URLs returned by
>   the API to be directly used or embedded in your applications**
>   (generally referred to as hotlinking). By using our CDN and embedding
>   the photo URLs in your application, we can better track photo views
>   and pass those stats on to the photographer, providing them with
>   context for how popular their photo is and how it’s being used.

https://unsplash.com/documentation

However I do think there is a valid use-case for loading a random image, and keeping the URL for re-use later, without going through their JSON API, so that's why I'm suggesting processing the 302 on the server side by means of an intermediate Ajax call.

To take it one step further, against Unsplash's preference, I would cache their images on my own servers.  If you were pulling their images manually that is absolutely what you'd do. At any point they could take their service down and your backgrounds would stop working.  A little thing like that is just a bit of assurance.  Maybe you could do both and use their CDN in preference to your own, but if their server goes tits up it would be nice to have a fallback.

Do look through their terms though and make your own call.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code in angularjs. it is so simple and good for use .

```
$http({
           method: "GET",
          url: "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=YourApplicationID&per_page=30&page="+$scope.pagenumber,

     }).then(
         function(res)
         {
            var totalFound=res.data.length;
            console.log('totalFound',res);
            var photo=[];

            for(var i=0;i<totalFound;i++)
            {
                var full=res.data[i].urls.full;
                var regular=res.data[i].urls.regular;
                var raw=res.data[i].urls.raw;
                var small=res.data[i].urls.small;
                var thumb=res.data[i].urls.thumb;

                photo.push({
                    full:full,
                    regular:regular,
                    raw:raw,
                    small:small,
                    thumb:thumb
                });

            }
            $scope.photo=photo;

         },
        function(res)
        {
            console.log('error',res);
        });
```

Thanks Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (unless there's more code you didn't include) this is because you haven't added the new Image object to the Dom, so the browser hasn't interpreted the redirect (301) from unsplash and given Angular an opportunity to catch up in a digest. My approach would be:

1. Instead of using an Image object, try using angular.element
2. Hide the element however you choose, or simply position it relatively and move it faaaar off canvas
3. Add that element to the Dom.
4. Use Timeout (add $timeout to your controller injectors) to then gain access to the resolved url

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
var elem = angular.element("<img>").src("https://source.unsplash.com/random");

// hard-code, or assign a class and style in your stylesheet, etc.
elem.css({position: 'absolute', "z-index":-1, top: -9999})

angular.element("body").append(elem);

$timeout(function()
{
    // use the raw DOM object's src instead of wrapped (angular) src
    var url = elem.get(0).src;

    // do whatever you need to with the URL

    // get rid of the element after it's been processed
    elem.remove();
});
```

Good luck!